# After switch to mongoDB auth::attempt does not work anymore

Tags: mongodb, authentication, laravel, hash, laravel-4

I recently switched my Laravel 4 Project to the mongoDB System using the jenssegers/laravel-mongodb Package.

The Seeds and migrations are fine, but the Auth::attempt function always returns false now. This worked quite nice before.

This is how the attribute looks like in the seeds:

```
'password' => Hash::make ( 'password' ),
```

This is how the data is compared by Auth::attempt:

```
        $userdata = array(
                'email'     =>Input::get('email'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password'),
        );
        $loginResult = Auth::attempt($userdata, $post_remember);
```

I inserted

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;
```

in all Models, Seeds, Migrations and the controller.

But auth.attempt ALWAYS returns false.

Comment: Are you sure the inputs are being passed properly. Just to check, hardcode the values and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Laravel 4 you can fix this by implementing "UserInterface" in your User model.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;
```

and then:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface

{
}
```

For Laravel 5:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract
{

    use Authenticatable;
}
```